# display predefined css class with custom border and background-color in CKEditor

Tags: css, ckeditor

I am using ckeditor in my project. I have added a button out of ckeditor area that when I click it adds sum html tag to the editor content. the code for click event of the button is as follows:

```
var oEditor = CKEDITOR.instances['myEditor'];
var html = '<span class=\'myclass\'>some text</span>';
var newElement = CKEDITOR.dom.element.createFromHtml( html, oEditor.document );
oEditor.insertElement( newElement );
```

now, I want to add some css code for class 'myclass' in CKEditor to show the tag different from another tags in editor. how can I do this ?
in other words, when I am working with editor I want to see myclass tags different in the editor.

Comment: did u configure your myclass in your css code ?

Comment: i mean like <style type="text/css"> .myclass{// your configuration }</style>

Comment: no, I don't know in which file I should add it. and I don't know what should I do after it.

Comment: add it in your main file .myclass{color:Red;} for example